# How can I downgrade an AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7 2.09.2 to an earlier 5.7 version?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, aws-aurora, aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

During a test, I applied a branch of our Terraform description that upgraded a couple Auroras from 5.7 2.04.x to 5.7 2.09.2 without losing the data (as expected). When attempting to apply the main branch, however, we realized Auroras are not easy to downgrade.

The solution (we were OK with losing the data) we used was to destroy the Aurora clusters manually, but that'd require a back-up and restore on a real cluster with data we wanted to preserve, assuming it's possible to do it across versions (which I'm no longer doing).

Since one of the key selling points of Aurora is the detachment of data storage and compute nodes, I was a bit surprised there is no easy way to revert an upgrade. Going to the console to modify the cluster manually no longer shows previous releases.

Is there a way to roll back changes without requiring to restore the data?

Comment: Amazon does not support rolling back as the internal tables are updated. All you can do is roll forward or, barring that, create a new instance and migrate the data